# Radasync Control Select button not visible in compatible view

Tags: telerik

I have working on RadAsync Upload, when i moved my code to server which has compatible view.
I am not able to see the RadAsync Select button.

Please help.

Comment: Show us what you've done, and provide further detail. And of course, do search and read previous questions before asking a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this link helps you

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload-select-button-not-visible.html

Try with EnableFileInputSkinning  property = false